# Accessing Incoming PUT Data from PHP/JQuery.ajax and how to handle it?

Tags: php, jquery, curl, put

I have an ajax call like this --

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'destination.php',
  type: "put",
  data: $('#myform').serialize(),
  success: function (response) {
     //some tasks
   }
 }
```

In My destination.php file how could i handle my form values that it is a  put request and use these values for other tasks such save them to database or in a file?  I am not an expert in PHP/JQuery/Ajax .Thanks.

Comment: if there is anything wrong with my question then i am sorry.Please someone help me...:(

Comment: check out with this link http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php

Comment: Thanks shanavascet .This is what i exactly wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example how to handle put vars:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$putVars);
echo $putVars['name']; // input from your form
```

but why are you using PUT and not POST?

Comment: great job Petros.To cover all the request types.Obviously i will use Post .Thanks :)